# How do I find the surface area of an angled conic base?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Thank you for viewing my question.

I need help creating a formula for finding the surface area of a conic base. (eg. I install a flood light on my roof, I want to know how much surface area it will cover).

What I know:

1. 25ft - The height of the light source above the ground
2. 30 degrees - The angle at which the light source is pointed towards the earth
3. 25 degrees - The vertical light beam width
4. 25 degrees The horizontal light beam width

Vertical light beam width is the angle in which the light emits horizontally from the lens of the light source. This creates a left and right limit.

Horizontal light beam width is the angle in which the light emits vertically from the lens of the light source. This creates a top and bottom limit.

[example of vertical light beam width and horizontal light beamwidth](http://michaeldmann.net/pix_7/astigma.gif)

Comment: There isn't enough info to solve your problem.  We need to know the cone angle of the light; otherwise, the result is independent of $h$.

Comment: Ron thanks for your time. Would my cone angle be the angle at which the light is pointing towards the earth. My vertical limit would emit no light higher than 55 degrees and no light lower than 5 degrees. The light would emit horizontally no further than 12.5 degrees both left and right of the light source.

Comment: No, the cone angle is the angle at which the light beams diverge from the source.  I see you have specified this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let $\theta$ be the angle the light is tilted, $\alpha$ be the horizontal beam divergence (width), $\beta$ be the vertical beam divergence, and $h$ be the height above the ground.

You should be able to convince yourself with right triangles that the horizontal beam width on the ground is

$$h \left[\tan{\left(\theta+\frac{\alpha}{2} \right)} - \tan{\left(\theta-\frac{\alpha}{2} \right)}\right] = \frac{2 h \tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\cos^2{\theta}-\sin^2{\theta} \tan^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} $$

There is an analogous expression for $\beta$.  The area of the beam (assuming a rectangular shape, add whatever geometrical factors you feel exist) is then

$$A = \frac{4 h^2 \tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}}{\left(\cos^2{\theta}-\sin^2{\theta} \tan^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right)\left(\cos^2{\theta}-\sin^2{\theta} \tan^2{\frac{\beta}{2}}\right)} $$

Using the given numbers, I get $A \approx 1123\, \text{ft}^2$.

Comment: I haven't checked your geometry, but I'll note that you can simplify the trig expressions considerably. For instance, $$\tan\left(\theta+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - \tan\left(\theta-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \frac{2\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha + \cos 2\theta}$$

Comment: @Blue: Thanks, I feel my expression is easier to check that the results are correct in the limit of $\theta \rightarrow 0$, but yours is shorter.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am running it on paper now to see if I can make sense of it all, I will get back to you all in a minute thanks again!

Comment: On the top half of the fraction did you get 121? I apologize for my lack of knowledge in high level mathematics.

Comment: @pyRabbit: I just did the calc in WA en masse, no idea what the numerator was.

Comment: This worked for me thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The illuminated region will be an ellipse. If the length and width of this ellipse are $a$ and $b$, then it's area is $\pi a b/4$.

If you don't know $a$ and $b$, then they will need to be calculated from the known quantities. I don't know what you mean by "vertical light beam width" and "horizontal light beam width", so I can't give any further help. A picture might help explain.

If these things are, in fact, $a$ and $b$, then we're done.

Comment: Bubba, thanks for your time. Sorry about the confusion so I went ahead and elaborated on the beam widths. Unfortunately a and b will be unknown. I need help finding a and b with the given information to find the surface area of an ellipse.